# Observables for Angular-forms

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-observable

I have a form on my site.(person.firstName, lastName, DOB, Gender, Citizenship, etc...). My question is how I can observe whole form changes and get from this observation 2 things:

- formControl with it's current status
- current value for handled formControl

  Prefix
              
                {{availablePrefix}}

  ```
        <div class="col">
          <label for="firstName">First Name<span style="color: red"> *</span> </label>
          <input formControlName="party.firstName" type="text" autocomplete="off" id="firstName"/>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
          <label for="middleName">Middle Name</label>
          <input formControlName="party.middleName" type="text" autocomplete="off" id="middleName" maxlength="1" />
        </div>

        <div class="col">
          <label for="lastName">Last Name<span style="color: red"> *</span> </label>
          <input formControlName="party.lastName" type="text" autocomplete="off" id="lastName"/>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
          <label for="suffix">Suffix</label>
          <select formControlName="party.suffix" id="suffix">
            <option [value]="availableSuffix" *ngFor="let availableSuffix of availableSuffixes">{{availableSuffix}}
            </option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  ```

thank you for any help

Comment: what do you mean ? formControl with it's current status

Comment: I mean 'dirty' or 'pristine', 'valid' or 'invalid'

Answer (score 4):

`valueChanges` observable alwayes will push the new value of the form.

In order to track the state of the form there are several properties for this  :

`status` The validation status of the control. There are four possible validation status values (`VALID , INVALID , PENDING, DISABLED`).

there is another observable to track the status change statusChanges

other readonly boolean properties to track the state of the form:

(`valid , invalid , pending , disabled , enabled , pristine , dirty , touched , untouched`)

you can track the old valeu state by this trick

```
  public form:FormGroup;
  oldValue:any;
  constructor (fb:FormBuilder) { 
     this.form = fb.group({
       name:[],
       lastName:[]
     });

     this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(newValue => { 
        console.log('old value',this.oldValue);
        this.oldValue = newValue;
        console.log('new form value',newValue);
        console.log('state ', this.form.status);
        console.log('pristine ',this.form.pristine);
        console.log('dirty ',this.form.dirty);
        console.log('touched ',this.form.touched);
     });
  }
```

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-state)

[AbstractControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl)

Answer (score 1):

Once your form is created (through the FormBuilder), simply write that :

```js
this.fmdForm.valueChanges.subscribe(formValue => { console.log(formValue); });
```

Comment: Thx, but how I can get formControl for this changed value?

Comment: `formValue` contains all of your form controls. Access them with `formValue.party.suffix`.

Comment: For the status, the old way : `this.fmdForm.get('party.suffix').valid`

Comment: I tried your answer. formValue contains only values without formControl's state

Comment: The state isn't bound to changes, the state is bound to the form. I made a comment just before yours to tell you how to get the state.